# Download Steam Game to Library

Tags: steam

I want to download a steam game since they're on sale, but my computer is good enough to run it, so i want to download it to my steam library, but not have it on my computer. Anyone know how to do this?

If you can't do that, then does anyone know how to download a game, then delete it from my computer without deleting it from my library?

Comment: Do you mean how can you add it to your Steam library without downloading it?

Comment: How do you download something *to* your Steam library? Your Steam library is just a list of games you own on Steam.

Comment: @Ktash yes I want to have it on my library, but not my computer

Answer (score 5):

By purchasing the game it will automatically be in your library. That allows you to install it on any computer you access with your steam account. So if you want to pick up a game on sale or even not on sale it will be in your library for use automatically. To play it on a different computer you will simply have to install it on that computer when you want to play.

Comment: And to finish this answer off, simply cancel out of the installation wizard in order to have the client not install the game on the current system.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How exactly would I do that?

Comment: @AntonioAnselmo: By clicking on the "Cancel" button.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams wouldn't that completely stop the download and take it out of my steam library?

Comment: @AntonioAnselmo no, it will always be in your library. you could install it completely or not install it at all and you could still install it on other computers because once you purchase it, it is always in your steam library

Comment: @AntonioAnselmo: No. You already own the game, therefore it is already in your library. It may not be visible, but can still be installed from its store page.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't see cancel, where would it be?

Comment: @AntonioAnselmo: At the bottom of the dialog box, next to "Next".